# Get facebook comments via open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to get all facebook comments from certain page via facebook api.

I'm checking comments using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/
If I check comments for test.com - I can see 77 coments of other peoples.

But when I'm trying to get comments by open graph method I get an empty answer:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?id=http://test.com
(I've tried encoded url also)

Am I missing something? Is there are some special requirements to get comments via open graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly it works if you add a trailing slash to the URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?id=http://test.com/
```

Comment: Does it work for you? I still get empty data answer:  {
   "data": [
      
   ]
}

Comment: Yes, empty answer, but maybe this site has not enable FB comments?

Comment: If you check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ and enter the http://test.com as URL for widget you can see that this site have 77 comments at this moment.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that in your question. Apparantly it's necessary to add a trailing slash to the URL in question: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?id=http://test.com/